# Does Timer.Change() ever return false?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

The .NET System.Threading Timer class has several overloaded Change() methods that return "true if the timer was successfully updated; otherwise, false."

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148.aspx

Does this method ever actually return false?  What would cause this to return false?

Comment: It does return `false` if you, eg. set it two times with the same values.

Comment: Thats weird, i can see in LinqPad the same timer returning false when i try to set the same paremeters a second time, i'll dig further into it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Joe Duffy (the development lead, architect, and founder of the Parallel 
Extensions to the .NET Framework team at Microsoft) detailed in *Concurrent Programming on Windows* p 373

> Note that although `Change` is typed as returning a `bool`, it will actually never return anything but true. If there is a problem changing the timer-such as the target object already having  been deleted-an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 7):

This can in fact return false if the unmanaged extern `ChangeTimerNative` were to return false. However, this is awfully unlikely.

Take note to Microsoft's code:

```
bool status = false;
bool bLockTaken = false; 

// prepare here to prevent threadabort from occuring which could
// destroy m_lock state.  lock(this) can't be used due to critical
// finalizer and thinlock/syncblock escalation. 
RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
try 
{ 
}
finally 
{
    do
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_lock, 1, 0) == 0) 
        {
            bLockTaken = true; 
            try 
            {
                if (timerDeleted != 0) 
                    throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, Environment.GetResourceString("ObjectDisposed_Generic"));
                status = ChangeTimerNative(dueTime,period);
            }
            finally 
            {
                m_lock = 0; 
            } 
        }
        Thread.SpinWait(1);     // yield to processor 
    }
    while (!bLockTaken);
}
return status;
```

**PLEASE NOTE** that the `ChangeTimerNative` calls the [`ChangeTimerQueueTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API function so you can read that documentation to get a feel for how it might fail.

Comment: Without showing the detail of `ChangeNativeTimer`, this doesn't tells us nothing different than the documentation for Timer.Change().

Comment: @RichAmberale: `ChangeTimerNative` calls this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, which still doesn't give any useful clues.

Comment: @mike How do you know `ChangeTimerNative` calls `ChangeTimerQueueTimer`?

Comment: @Tudor: that is correct in that there isn't much useful, but that's about as far as anybody can go unless there's somebody that has Microsoft's OS code right?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, a little work with reflector and some validating opinions.  :)

Comment: @PeterRitchie: here is another validating opinion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772078/behaviour-of-system-timer-when-interval-property-changed)

Comment: @Mike, I think I'll go with the word of someone who works at Microsoft and the architect of .NET Parallel Extensions...

Comment: @PeterRitchie: fair enough, I mean it's not what you know but who you know in this world friend. I guess that just invalidates my answer huh?

Comment: @Mike BTW, what Hans is referring to is SSCLI which is an "open source" version of the .NET 2.0 era CLI, it was *not* how .NET 2.0 was implemented exactly.  And both the native and CLR thread pools have changed since then.

Answer (score 5):

On checking the managed source, the only case in which it returns false is if the AppDomain timer (if one does not exist, it is created) represented by a private class `AppDomainTimerSafeHandle` - has `SafeHandle.IsInvalid` set to true.

Since AppDomainTimerSafeHandle inherits from [SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandlezeroorminusoneisinvalid.aspx), IsInvalid is implemented by it - when a timer is attempted to be created by the unmanaged infrastructure and ends up with a Safe-Handle which is reading from the definition Zero-Or-Minus-One-Is-Invalid.

All cases point to this being extremely unlikely.

Comment: Are you talking about the `Change` method or something else?  `Change` does not create a timer...

Comment: @PeterRitchie It amounts to an entry in the Timer queue. I've edited it to make it a bit more clearer.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I guess I should delete this answer before the downvotefags  come along.

Comment: It's still not clear how this applies to the `Change` method.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Change returns false if the AppDomain's Timer has a handle which equals Zero or One. Why are you asking again if I've got the wrong method?

Comment: because the code I'm looking at in `Change` does not do that.

Comment: I'm looking at `System.Threading.TimerQueue, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0`.

Comment: `System.Threading.Timer.Change` does nothing with a `System.Threading.TimerQueue` object...

Comment: @PeterRitchie I have no reason to make this up. It's highly likely we're looking at two implementations of the same thing. You are most likely looking in `System.dll`.